# Stock info while restocking

Tags: tiny-tower

Is there a way to get a stock information while currently restocking a floor?
For example, I'm currently restocking my fast food with fries. It already has nuggets and burgers in stock but if I want to know how many, when clicking on the floor, I only get the progress bar of the fries restocking.
Is there then a way or any indication to get this information?

Comment: iOS or android ??

Comment: @Foxtrot I'm on iOS (iPad version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to view the current level of stock while restocking within that same store.  The only indication of current level stock is shown while looking at the tower(not the specific restocking floor) if it is > 0 as Ebongo stated.

View the screen shots below.

Here you notice, you can view the current stock level of each item while **not restocking any other item**.

[image]

Below is shown the same floor being restocked.  Now it only shows the progress level of restocking and currently stocked information is hidden.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For iOS (and possibly other platforms) I believe there is no way to see the exact amount, once you start restocking.  You can see an icon that merely indicates that your stock in that item is > 0.  The icons are shown just to the left of the store name.

Comment: It's the same on Android as well